# how to gzip or compress a .json file and use it in the frontend .js

Tags: javascript, json, apache, tomcat, gzip

i have big json file that i load in the index.js On page load (javascript) file which leads to increase in the time of loading the page.

What should i use to reduce this so that the page loads fast?

Comment: <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
               compression="on" 
         compressionMinSize="2048" 
         noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"  compressableMimeType="text/html,
text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/json"/>                                                             I have added this but its still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable gzip on your server level, In configuration **compressableMimeType** you can specify which type of data to be compressed.

```
  <Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8444"
compression="on" compressableMimeType="text/html,
text/xml,text/plain,text/javascript,text/css,application/json" />
```

You can visit http://viralpatel.net/blogs/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat/ for configuration steps

Comment: Can this gzip work with $.getJSON to access the contents?

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache configuration, set mod_deflate parameters. [See here for complete doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html)

Depending on your configuration, apache config could be located:

Windows C:\Program Files\Apache Group\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf
Linux: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf